# BroadcastReceiver for call answers

Tags: android, android-intent, telephony, intentservice, telephonymanager

I'm trying to programmatically intercept a call answer.

I've got a BroadcastReceiver with the following method:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String state = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        if(state.equals("OFFHOOK")) {
            // ...
        }
        // ANSWER ??
    }
}
```

While the code works successfully if the phone receives a call (offhook is related to the answer, because before I've got the ringing state) I can't detect the answer relatively to a placed call: in this case offhook is relative to the ringing.

How can I intercept the answer relatively to a placed call?

Comment: Try this : http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/get-phone-state-when-someone-is-calling_22.html

Comment: That's pretty similar to my attempt... but it doesn't work properly for outgoing calls...